# Link-Checking with Multi-Curl

Tags: php, curl, curl-multi

Im building a Link Checker function that checks if the link has code 200/301/302.

I want to check about 1000 links so i I used the Multi-CURL functionality and i do get all the headers, codes, the URL to which a URL redirected.

The Problem is that Multi-CURL executes in parallel adding all the URLs to curl_multi_add_handle and returns the results it gets and ignores the rest.

I know from the header which result i got back but i dont know which URL brought it. Is there an Identifier which URL i requested against a specific executed handle (may be something to do with curl_multi_info_read )?

Here my Code:

```
$curls = $listofurls;
$curl_arr = array();
          $master = curl_multi_init();

          for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++) {

            $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init($curls[$i][0]);
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i],CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,true);
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i],CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i],CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i],CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'HEAD');
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i],CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i],CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i],CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i],CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30);

            curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$i]);
          }


          $finalresult = array();

          do{

            curl_multi_exec($master, $running);
            $info = curl_multi_info_read($master);

            if($info['handle']) {
              $finalresult[] = curl_multi_getcontent($info['handle']);
              curl_multi_remove_handle($master, $info['handle']);
            }

          $previousActive = $running;
          }
          while($running > 0);

           curl_multi_close($master);
```

Appreciate the Help.Thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it solved-Its the returned Order thats important to understand and combine with the result. For someone who may be looking for the answer:

```
      $curls = $listofurls;
      $curl_arr = array();
      $master = curl_multi_init();

      for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++) {

        $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init($curls[$i][0]);
        curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i],CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,true);
        curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i],CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
        curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i],CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
        curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i],CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'HEAD');
        curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i],CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i],CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
        curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i],CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i],CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30);

        curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$i]);
      }



          $finalresult = array();
          $returnedOrder = array();

          do{

            curl_multi_exec($master, $running);
            $info = curl_multi_info_read($master);

            if($info['handle']) {
              $finalresult[] = curl_multi_getcontent($info['handle']);
              $returnedOrder[] = array_search($info['handle'], $curl_arr, true);
              curl_multi_remove_handle($master, $info['handle']);
              curl_close($curl_arr[end($returnedOrder)]);
            }

          $previousActive = $running;
          }
          while($running > 0);

          $res = array_combine($returnedOrder, $finalresult);
          curl_multi_close($master);
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer. I was having the same issue of how to figure out the order.